# Does U-Sql support cursors for iterating through data sets and extracting more data based on row values?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Does Azure Data Lake Analytics and U-SQL support the notion of Cursors in scripts?

I have a data set that contains paths to further data sets I would like to extract and I want to output the results to separate files.

At the moment I can't seem to find a solution for dynamically extracting and outputting data based on values inside data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U-SQL currently expect that files are known at compile time. Thus, you cannot do extraction or outputting based on locations provided inside a file.

You can specify filesets in the `EXTRACT` statement that will be somewhat data driven. We are currently working on adding the ability to use filesets on `OUTPUT` as well.

You can file feature requests at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Cheers
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to write a Processor to iterate over the rows in the primary dataset. However, you might not be able to access the additional datasets in the Processor.

Another work around might be to concatenate all the additional datasets and perform a join with the primary dataset.